# Handlebars link-to helper doesn't work in an Ember layout

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember layout like this:

```
{{#link-to 'dashboard'}}
    dashboard
{{/link-to}}

testing

{{yield}}
```

The link-to breaks it, resulting in: `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

As a result, nothing is rendered. If I take the `link-to` out the page renders again. How can I fix this?

Comment: the link-to is fine, can show a little more of what you're doing?  You can use emberjs.jsbin.com to get started if you can show it in an example

Comment: Thanks. That's much nicer than jsfiddle! Replicated here http://emberjs.jsbin.com/eHoCeNA/2/edit - results in a script error; removing the #link-to part makes it render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you posted above, you are reopening the Ember.View and attempting to apply the layoutName to every single view in the application (which is probably causing some sort of recursive problem as a view may insert a view etc).

If you feel like sharing the layout and don't want to type it a few times you can create a view that has it, and have your other views extend that view

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
  layoutName: 'layouts/app2'
});

App.IndexView = App.MyView.extend();
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/eHoCeNA/6/edit